# How to get text from a constructor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, pdf-reader

I'm stuck at using text that is created in a constructor outside the constructor.

Actually, I'm trying to read a pdf file using pdfreader node module. I'm able to print pdf data word by word as text in below constructor.

```
fs.readFile(pdfFilePath, (err, pdfBuffer) => {
    // pdfBuffer contains the file content
    new pdfreader.PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item){
        if (err)
        callback(err);
        else if (!item)
        callback();
        else if(item.text !== undefined)
        console.log(item.text);
    });
 });
```

But I want to get that text into some string or array and I need to check whether a piece of text is there in the whole string or array.

I am not able to do this.

Comment: concat each of the item.text to a variable and then find the indexOf what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you John, for the suggestion. But it's not working. Is this what you mentioned?

Comment: var a = '';
     var pdfreader = require('pdfreader');
     let pdfFilePath = 'C:/Users/Downloads/';
     fs.readFile(pdfFilePath, (err, pdfBuffer) => {
          new PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item){
                        if (err)
                        callback(err);
                        else if (!item)
                        callback();
                        else if(item.text)
                        a.concat(item.text);
                        console.log(a);
                    }); });
                console.log('after block' + a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = '';
var pdfreader = require('pdfreader');
let pdfFilePath = 'C:/Users/Downloads/';
fs.readFile(pdfFilePath, (err, pdfBuffer) => {
    new PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        else if (!item) callback();
        else if(item.text !== undefined)
        a = a.concat(item.text);
    });
});
console.log('after block' + a)
```

Try this. I'm unsure if the `item.text` considers a space or not.

Comment: Thank you concat worked but a small tweak, a = a.concat(item.text) will work as concat will result in a new string and a will be an empty string for the next iteration.